# Irrational Numbers and Surjection from $[0,1)$ to $[0,1)^2$

Tags: irrational-numbers, decimal-expansion

I am searching for some clues or solutions of the question below:
For $\sqrt{2}=1.41421356\cdots$,

Is $1.1236\cdots$ irrational?

To say more formally:
Let $f$ a function from $[0,1)$ to  $[0,1)^2$  defined that for any real number x represented as $0.x_1x_2x_3\cdots$ in decimal (it is assumed that 9 never appears indefinitely now), $f(x)=(0.x_1x_3x_5\cdots, 0.x_2x_4x_6\cdots)$.

It is famous fanction as what is surjective but not injective, I wonder if $f(\sqrt{2}-1)=(0.1236\cdots,0.4415\cdots)$ has rational component.

This ploblem is not easy.
If you don't think so, I want you to think about $f(0.040104020\cdots)=(\sqrt2-1,0)$

I thought many conditions for irrational numbers can't be used for this.

I'm sorry for my poor English.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I would not be surprised if this is an open question.

Comment: Almost nothing is known about decimal expansions of this kind of constants. For example, we don't know if all digits appear infinitely often. For all we know it could be the case that the decimal expansion of $\sqrt 2$ have only a finite number of digits $2, 3, \ldots, 9$ and from some point onward  be $\ldots 01001000100001000001 \cdots$. Determining if the number formed from digits in the even (or odd) positions is eventually periodic looks way harder.

Comment: At least one of the two number of the pair is irrational.  Probably both.

Comment: just an idea, is it possible to express the continued fractions of the split numbers, since $\sqrt{2}$ has a periodic continued fraction maybe this gives something usable ?

Comment: @zwim It doesn't look good: the continued fractions are $[0, 2, 3, 1, 3, 2, 4, 1, 13, 1, 2, 1, 3, 12,\ldots]$ and $[1, 8, 11, 3, 5, 16, 3, 3, 1, 4, 38, 2, 1, 4, 4, 1,\ldots]$, nothing related with $[1,2,2,2,2,\ldots]$

Comment: ok, at least we know it leads nowhere.